# my List<> returns 0 instead of the result

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to get 5 random cards from my populated deck and deletes them from the deck. The List n works fine in Player.java but when passed back to main, it returns the deleted results.

```
public class Player {
private Random r = new Random();
int res;
List<Card> n = new ArrayList<>();
public List<Card> Deal(List<Card> deck){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
        Card c = Draw(deck);
        n.add(c);
        System.out.println(res + n.get(i).getSuit() + n.get(i).getFigure());
        DelCard(deck.get(res));
    }
    return n;
}

public Card Draw(List<Card> deck){
    res = r.nextInt(deck.size());
    Card c = deck.get(res);
    return c;
}

private Card DelCard(Card c){
    c.setFigure("0");
    c.setSuit("0");
    return c;
}
```

}

Here is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Exercise04 e = new Exercise04();
    e.run();
}

public void run(){
    List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Card> pDeck1 = new ArrayList<>();
    deck = popDeck(deck, fig, suit);
    Player p1 = new Player();
    pDeck1 = p1.Deal(deck);
    printDeck(pDeck1);
    //printDeck(deck);
}
```

Here's a sample output:

> 27D2
>       23SJ
>       51CK
>       5H6
>       21S9
>       00
>       00
>       00
>       00
>       00

Comment: You're not really deleting anything.  You're just changing some variables to `"0"`.  That doesn't magically make the card go away.  And if `Draw` happens to use a random value that returns one of the cards with `"0"`, it will return it since you haven't done anything to tell it not to return cards like that.

Comment: The logic in your code for `Deal()` looks correct. So you are doing a `for` loop for 5 times, and for each round you are drawing a card from `deck` and you call `n.add( the_drew_card)`, then you remove from the `deck`. Lastly you return `n` which is a list of deleted cards. Note that `n` is static, essentially you don't even have to return `n` because you could do `Player.n` and it still gives you the result.

Comment: @SamuelToh Sorry I did not mean to declare n as static. I changed it now. I really want to return `n` so that `pDeck1` will receive it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove key static from the line 
static List n = new ArrayList<>();
and what is popDeck method supposed to do?

--> also it seems that delete method is defined properly yet.

replace DelCard method with it.

```
private void DelCard(List<Card> deck)
{
deck.remove(deck.get(res));
}
```

Comment: It populates the deck in which I will get the random results in drawing.

Comment: you are calling delete method by passing uninitialized variable res, i think your logic suggests to pass card "c" here.

Comment: variable res gets initialized in draw method before delete method. I have a comment in printing and it works fine but when I pass it back to main, I only have "00" results in the list.

Comment: to debug the problem place one more system.println line right after DelCard method call.

Comment: you are getting card through variable "res" in Draw method and same card you pass to DelCard, so DelCard changes the values of cards that are to return.

Comment: pass deck to DelCard method and remove "res" card from deck, do not change values of card's faces.

Comment: got it now. Thanks! :D